# AWS EKS - Use Kubernetes config file on environment that doesn't have AWS CLI installed

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to get a Kubernetes config file in AWS EKS which doesn't contain a call to AWS CLI? The goal is to use this config file in environment that doesn't have AWS CLI installed.